# Worst time complexity (Big O) for 1 for loop

Tags: c#, time-complexity, big-o

So I understand most complexity problems; however, this puzzles me.

When the second statement in the for loop is as below (i * i < n), what would tre Big O for the loop be? How would it be calculated?

```
for ( i = 1 ; i * i < n ; i++)
```

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that `n` is a proxy for the size of the input (and that your code will only execute the loop body once for each processable member of the input, and there is no other input element selector logic).

```
i * i < n
  i^2 < n
    i < Sqrt(n)
```

So, a time complexity of `O( Floor( Sqrt( n ) ) )`.

Let's see an example with `n = 10` (the table shows the state of the variables at the end of each iteration, at the moment exactly before `i++` is evaluated and the `i * i < n` test is performed).

```
Iteration,   i,   i * i,  n
        1,   1,       1, 10
        2,   2,       4, 10
        3,   3,       9, 10
        4,   4,      16, 10 -- 16 > 10, abort loop
        5,   5,      25, 10 -- for illustrative purposes
```

(Note that as the `i^2 < 10` check is performed *before* the loop is executed, iteration 4 will not be executed, so the loop will be executed 3 times. The exact square-root of 10 is `3.1622...` but iteration-counts are 0-based natural numbers, so use `Floor`.).

Comment: Great explanation of *how* `i * i < n` is equivalent to `i < sqrt(n)`

Answer (score 6):

```
i*i<n
```

can be transformed as

```
i<sqrt(n)
```

So its acutally `O(sqrt(n))`

Comment: Huh, I've never actually encountered that form, only O(n) with various exponents, O(logn) or (n logn), and constant of course. So can it actually be written "O(√n)", is that an accepted "syntax"?

Comment: @mbksr Correct. Any algebraic expression (and notation) can be used in `O()`. Note that `O()` is not necessarily a function of `n` either, for example if you're processing a 2D array (in which case it's a function of `m` and `n` for width and height respectively).

Comment: @mbksr `O()` can be used with any kind of function. Its merely a way to express there is a relation between the growth of two functions: [wiki article about the notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)